# Automatic way to export each function as a method of main

Tags: javascript, node.js, methods, module, commonjs

I just create a node module that is a single file that contains many functions for instance:

```
function alpha () {
  return 'alpha'
}

function beta () {
  return 'beta'
}

function main () {
  return alpha() + beta() + 'gamma'
}

module.exports = main
```

The problem with this is that what I really want is all of the declared functions (other then `main`) to be methods of `main`, like `main.alpha` (note `main` in this case would not be a object with prototypes). I would want all of these functions as methods so I can still export one function `main` and be able to use `main.alpha()` outside of this module.

With this said I'm stuck with the functions in the module the way I authored them. I can go in and change every function declaration (`function (.+) \(`) to `main.$1 = function (` with my text-editor's (atom's) find & replace regex function.

There are some 20 functions in the module that I created and editing all the code is very tedious & involved. Another issue is that every function name becomes a lot less easier to recognize when it's being used rather then a nice `getFiles` function I have an unnecessarily long `main.getFiles` function.

My desired result is to the effect of this (fig 1):

```
function main () {
  return main.alpha() + main.beta() + 'gamma'
}

main.alpha = function  {
  return 'alpha'
}

main.beta = function () {
  return 'beta'
}

module.exports = main
```

or this (fig 2)

```
function alpha () {
  return 'alpha'
}

function beta () {
  return 'beta'
}

function main () {
  return alpha() + beta() + 'gamma'
}

main.alpha = alpha
main.beta = beta

module.exports = main
```

My question is: *Is there a way to author a CommonJS module in a way where I can declare functions as I have (as above) and easily add all declared functions within the module as methods of `main`?*

My only options seem to be:

1. Go through each function in the module, and replace function decorations like this `function (.+) \(` to a method of main like this `main.$1 = function (`, then go through and find each use of the function and replace it to the main method. (fig 1)
2. At the end of the file when main and all of the functions have been declared, add methods to main that are equal to the original function. (Eg. `main.getFiles = getFiles`) (fig 2)

**Update 1**

One way to go about this is to get the `global` variables at the beginning of the module and at the end, then `diff` them to get the variables created within the module then build a string map I can just paste into the end of the module, that assign all of the methods to the main function. Sadly new function declarations within main aren't getting attached to `global`. You can see here `global['main']` logs `undefined`.

```
function main () {

}

console.log(global['main']) // => undefined
```

**Update 2**

I'd also love a solution like this, it would allowed me to add a variable definition to a named function. I'd like to be able to call it internally as the named function and it would export as a method of main. This doesn't work though.

```
function main () {
  return alpha() + beta() + 'gamma'
}

main.alpha = function alpha () {
  return 'alpha'
}

main.beta = function beta () {
  return 'beta'
}

module.exports = main
```

**Update 3**

This works!

```
function main () {
  return alpha() + beta() + 'gamma'
}

var alpha = main.alpha = function () {
  return 'alpha'
}

var beta = main.beta = function () {
  return 'beta'
}

module.exports = main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The code is what it is.  Javascript does only what you tell it to do.  If you don't declare a function to be a property of `main`, then it won't be a property of `main`.

You could develop your own text preprocessor that would change all top level functions to be properties of `main` - basically just changing the source code to declare them that way.  There are several different methods you could use for identifying the right functions - ranging from a structured comment on the preceding line to code that actually detects which function declarations are at the top level.

Unfortunately, Javascript does not supply any way to iterate all items declared within a scope.  To be able to iterate them, they have to be properties of an object, not just declarations within a scope.  So, Javascript does not provide any way to iterate all top level functions in a module (remember the top level in a module is actually not the global level, but is within a module function scope).  This means you can't iterate functions defined within a scope from your own Javascript to change this with your own JS.

---

You haven't really explained why just declaring the functions as proper properties as you want them is such a burden.

If you want a single line of code that will both make your functions be properties of `main` and define a local symbol that can be used, you can do it like this:

```
var alpha = main.alpha = function() {...};
```

Comment: I started the module off by creating very short named functions, starting with 1 or 2. Now I have over 20, and because I authored them without being a method I have a decision to make. I would like to have all the functions be methods of main so I can use them outside this module. I just want to make sure that the decision I make is an educated one. It seems between the two options I listed, 2 is better, so I don't have to go through the source and replace every function declaration and usage. Any preference? Or alternatives? My dream would be for `this` at module scope to have all local vars.

Comment: @ThomasReggi - I personally like your fig. 1 option because it's clear right in the definition what the declaration is being used as and there's no separate place in the file where you're maintaining something related to that function.  Yep, I do kind of wonder why JS didn't make a way to iterate the items within a scope since certainly it has such a data structure internally.  But, they didn't do it.  You have to put things in an object if you want to iterate them.

Comment: Check update 2 & 3. 2 does not work, but 3 does! Which means that I can just apply one regex to update my code. `function (.+) \(` => `main.$1 = $1 = function (` & I can still call the functions cleanly from within the module.

Comment: @ThomasReggi - it looks like option 3 is creating symbols without `var` or `function`.  I wouldn't think that would work in strict mode.  Wouldn't the symbol `alpha` be an implicit global which is a no-no.

Comment: @ThomasReggi - yes, I just verified that option 3 is creating implicit global symbols (a no-no) and will not work in strict mode.  You'd have to do it as `var alpha = main.alpha = function() {...}`;